# Get weekends between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have done the following so far:

```
declare @date int=7
declare @curDate date=getdate()

create table #temp(dat date,day1 varchar(max))

while @date>0
begin
insert into #temp values(@curDate,DATENAME(DW,@curDate))
set @curDate=DATEADD(Day,-1,@curDate)
if(DATENAME(DW,@curDate)<>'Saturday' and DATENAME(DW,@curDate)<>'Sunday')
  begin
 set @date=@date-1
  end

  End

  select * from #temp
```

By this code i can easily find if there is a weekend between two date or not.

My question is:

> Is there any other way to find if between two dates got a weekend or
>   not

e.g

> date1 '03-25-2015' and date2 '03-30-2015' got a weekend or not??

Example/Expected Output:

```
table1
(
id bigint, 
value1 varchar(50),
value2 decimal(18,2),
.
.
.
date1 date
)
```

> let passdate1(firstdate(min)) and passdate2(last date (max)) is two
>   given date:

I want it like this:

```
select * from table1 where date1 between case 
when (passdate1,passdate2) has weekend and it's no is 2 days
then passdate1 and dateadd(day,2,passdate2) 
else
passdate1 and passdate2 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use recursive common table expressions to select all dates, then use `DATEPART` to determine if each date is a weekend

```
;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CONVERT( DATE, '2015-01-01' ) AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( DAY, 1, a )
    FROM   dates
    WHERE  DATEADD( DAY, 1, a ) < '2015-02-01'
)
SELECT a
FROM   dates
WHERE  DATEPART( dw, a ) IN ( 1, 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "between". Does it have to be a full two-day weekend? Are the endpoints ever weekend days themselves? Are the endpoint dates ever the same?

I'm not quite sure how you're using the code above. You could possibly check that `(select count(*) from #temp) < datediff(dd, @date1, @date2)` but I don't get the impression you had that in mind.

Does this work for you? It would detect a full weekend when @date1 and @date2 are always weekdays.

```
datediff(dd, @date1, @date) > 5 or datepart(dw, @date2) < datepart(dw, @date1)
```

I'm assuming a weekend of Saturday and Sunday with day numbering that begins on Sunday.

Comment: This would be dependent on SET DATEFIRST   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Are already noted that.

Comment: yes, it's working and i can find the no of days and possible everything from it. but my question is, is there any other way to find if between two dates i.e `date1` and i.e `date2` has a weekend  or not. @shawnt00

Comment: I need to understand precisely what you mean by "has a weekend". See the comments in my answer.

Comment: sorry, please,let me update my question again.@shawnt00

Comment: see now, if you have any question then ask,.
i can do it using a store procedure or function call but i'm asking for something different or easy or in a single like code.

Comment: I recognize that language is a hurdle here. But I did ask three specific questions which you did not attempt to address. Unfortunately most of what you added makes little sense to me.

Comment: It appears that you want to detect when passdate2 falls on a "weekend" and then advance it 2 days (regardless of which of the weekend days that actually was.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73701/discussion-between-user3540365-and-shawnt00).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution which, essentially, computes difference in weeks between two dates and if those dates are equals it returns 0:

```
SELECT  *, 
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, StartDate, EndDate) AS NumOfWeekends
FROM (VALUES 
    ('2015-03-03', '2015-03-25'),
    ('2015-03-03', '2015-03-03'),
    ('2015-03-03', '2015-03-07'),
    ('2015-03-03', '2015-03-08'),
    ('2015-03-07', '2015-03-08'),
    ('2015-03-07', '2015-03-07'),
    ('2015-03-08', '2015-03-08'),
    ('2015-03-03', NULL)
) x(StartDate, EndDate);

/*
Output:
StartDate  EndDate    NumOfWeekends
---------- ---------- -------------
2015-03-03 2015-03-25 3
2015-03-03 2015-03-03 0
2015-03-03 2015-03-07 0
2015-03-03 2015-03-08 1
2015-03-07 2015-03-08 1
2015-03-07 2015-03-07 0
2015-03-08 2015-03-08 0
2015-03-03 NULL       NULL
*/
```

Note: `DATEDIFF(WEEK` isn't dependent on `@@DATEFIRST` setting according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @sd DATE = '20150326', @ed DATE = '20150329'

IF DATEDIFF(dd, @sd, @ed) >= 7 OR ( DATEPART(dw, @sd) = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @ed) = 1 )
       OR ( DATEDIFF(dd, @sd, @ed) >= 2 AND DATEPART(dw, @sd) > DATEPART(dw, @ed) )
    PRINT 'YES'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NO'
```